# Gwan include scripts

Tags: c, include, pragma, g-wan

I am currently trying to import some libraries into my Gwan C script. I have read through the manual and am using `#pragma include` to include the folder that my libraries are in, and then use `#pragma link` to actually include the libraries, but when I run the script it error and says `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxxxx.a`

Heres current code

```
#pragma include "/opt/Gwan/libraries/xxx"
#pragma link "xxxx.a"
```

current Gwan version 4.3.11. Thanks, any help will be appreciated

[EDIT]
All is working fine now, changed all my libraries to shared and placed them in /usr/lib

Answer (score 0):

While you can link *object code* and *static libraries* with G-WAN scripts, you should rather use a *dynamic library* because it will only be loaded once in memory.

Do you succeed in running the (many) G-WAN examples that use third-party libraries?
(libsqlite, libcairo, libmySQL, libcURL, liboauth, libmemchached, ImageMagick, etc.)

Don't forget that you must indicate the library file name *without* the starting "lib" prefix (ie: `sqlite3` for `libsqlite3.so`).

Also, libraries compiled for 64-bit won't work with G-WAN 32-bit (and vice-versa).

If this can help, there's a [G-WAN FAQ dedicated on libraries](http://gwan.com/faq#use_libraries) which gives tips and tools to check for possible problems.

Maybe you should give the whole library names instead of the `xxx` in your example.